# asp.net mvc validation messages localization for numbers (data-val-number)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, localization, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change 'data-val-number' message validation in MVC while it generate by helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828297/how-to-change-data-val-number-message-validation-in-mvc-while-it-generate-by-h)

Main question is: Where 'data-val-number' message comes from? From what validation rule?

We are localizing our ASP.Net MVC 3 application. For localizing validation messages we decided to use DataAnotationExtension package. So, for each attribute to be localized there is a simple Localized+*AttributeName*+AttributeAdapter.cs which takes validation rule from attribute and changes validation message. The only problem we have is Numbers. Validation message for numbers comes to client like that:

```
data-val-number="The field CurrencyAmmount must be a number."
```

and we don`t know where it comes from.

Comment: there is another solution for this problem, described in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828297/how-to-change-data-val-number-message-validation-in-mvc-while-it-generate-by-h But we have already chosen another way.

Comment: which other way did you choose?

Comment: @NelsonReis There were only several places where we needed this attribute so we choosen the simplest way: directly add this attribute to page element.`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SomeFloat, new { data_val_number = "Custom validation massege" })`

Comment: I've used [Griffin MVC Contrib](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/352583/Localization-in-ASP-NET-MVC-with-Griffin-MvcContri) project to localize the validation texts without ugly attributes