# How to change default validation error message in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have common issue to that [How to change default validation error message in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214066/how-to-change-default-validation-error-message-in-asp-net-mvc)

I'm trying to set default validation message for all types in app but I use MVC3 and Razor engine. Unfortunately ssg solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please elaborate and show some code which ain't working....Right now, it's impossible to understand what problems are you having

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Model Metadata and Validation Localization using Conventions](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/07/14/model-metadata-and-validation-localization-using-conventions.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but..

I just create C# validation code to determine if it isn't valid then return a validation message for an invalid string length.

```
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ValidEIN))
    {
        Validation.Add("EIN",
        Validator.StringLength(0, 0, "Employee ID doesn't exist.")
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a problem in MVC3. http://forums.asp.net/t/1512140.aspx/1/10

Here are 2 possible workarounds.

1) Write a custom validation attribute with your own error message.

2) Do it client-side. Create a custom ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider, how to do this with MVC2 is explained [here](http://jwwishart.blogspot.com.au/2011/03/custom-server-and-client-side-required.html), I haven't tried it for MVC3. There is also some good info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828297/how-to-change-data-val-number-message-validation-in-mvc-while-it-generate-by-h).